# Kotlin Generics type parameters

Tags: generics, kotlin, contravariance

At the following source code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")

    val mutableIntList = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)

    addInt(4, mutableIntList) // No compile-time error
    addAnotherInt(5, mutableIntList) // Compile-time error

    println(mutableIntList)

}

fun <T: Number> addInt(item:T,
                       list:MutableList<in T>){
    list.add(item)
}

fun <T: Number> addAnotherInt(item:T,
                              list:MutableList<in Number>){
    list.add(item)
}
```

The functions `addInt` and `addAnotherInt` take as an argument a contravariant `MutableList` of `Number`. But at the `main` function one line compiles normally and the other is not.

I also checked the generated java code from these functions and they seem identical.

What could be the difference between the functions `addInt` and `addAnotherInt`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`in Number` means "`Number` or its supertype". `Int` is not a "`Number` or its supertype", it is its subtype.

In plain words, you declared that your `addAnotherInt()` wants a list that is at least as general as accepting any kind of `Number`.

By contrast, `addInt` declares `item: T` and `list: MutableList<in T>`. `T` itself is declared as a *free type variable* for the function, which means it will be bound at each specific call site. So when you say

```
addInt(4, mutableIntList)
```

Kotlin binds `T` to `Int` based on the first argument and propagates this to the second argument, which is now `MutableList<in Int>`. You passed in a `MutableList<Int>` which is compatible with that type, so Kotlin is satisified.

If you declared

```
val mutableIntList: MutableList<Number> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
```

then the code would compile because now the list is as general as required, and you can add any `Number` to it.

Comment: My respect for the perfect phrasing of contravariance, `at least as general as accepting any kind of Number`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will compile with a number list:

```
val mutableIntList = mutableListOf<Number>(1, 2, 3)
```

But since the type is inferred to `MutableList<Int>`, you can't use it as a `MutableList<in Number>`. This translates to the *Java* equivalent `MutableList<? super Number>` and means that you can add any `Number` to the list. But adding a `Long` to the `MutableList<Int>` is not possible.

Your second method `addInt()` is a little more strict and translates `MutableList<? super Int>` in your usecase. Thus you can use it as such. Both methods are capable of using a `MutableList<Number>` though.